# Photo selector dialog

Tags: facebook, dialog, photo

I think I have seen a Facebook photo selector dialog which allowed the user to select an album and then a photo. But searching Facebook's documentation, this doesn't seem to exist.

Does anybody know any widget to accomplish this (target platform is desktop/Javascript)?

Does anybody know if this dialog actually existed once or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it did exist about two years ago, but does not any more. 
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector/

You need to do it yourself through FQL to get the friends, and a bit of CSS and HTML (and Javascript to  multiple entries). googling gives other options: http://archives-mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Though I'm talking about a photo selector, not a friend selector. Do you know if this actually existed?

Comment: Sorry. But to answer the real question, i've never seen a photo selector and always written my own (at least in the last three years, which is most of Facebook's "modern" life.) Sorry for misreading the question, but the answer is still pretty much the same.